# How to separate webpack common config into prod only

Tags: angularjs, build, webpack, webpack-dev-server

So I configed my webpack like this https://github.com/adamchenwei/webpack-starter-angular/compare/master...adamchenwei:feature/build-for-windows

The change is in `feature/build-for-windows`. That change fixed my sourcemap not found issue, but prod build is broken though dev environment works perfectly. Do anyone know how to further break this change into the prod config instead of what I did now which put into common, which shared by both prod and dev? Or can I somehow disable that setup on prod maybe?

If you run my repo in that branch, you will see error like I stated in this `issue` https://github.com/kitconcept/webpack-starter-angular/issues/13

Not able to resolve it for the build in prod command.

You have to download the whole repo and do `npm run build:prod:win` to reproduce the issue.

Any advise will be appreciated!

Comment: can you more specific what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @MrJSingh updated!